# How do I break up a giant merge in git?

Tags: git, merge

First my project was like this:

```
A
```

Then a developer made a huge change (with many commits):

```
A -> B
```

Another developer made a huge change (with many commits) at the same time:

```
A -> B
 \
  -> C
```

Now I need to merge back C. A git diff shows that about 5000 out of the roughly 10000 LOC is different in C vs master (B). Not to mention numerous external library changes.

First I tried making a branch C_merge off B and merging in C. This resulted in one huge commit with many conflicts which I resolved, after which I had loads of compile errors.

I would like to try the rebase approach. I would like to branch off C (in case somebody adds more commits to C), then rebase on B, going through it one commit at a time and get it compiling and passing unit tests all along the way. Is this possible, and if so, what commands do I run? Or is there a better way?

Comment: It sounds like the developer needs to merge master into their branch before merging C into master. You could also try `git diff -w` to exclude whitespace differences to see if the change is smaller than advertised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `git rebase -i`, which is rebase in interactive mode.  Before git does every commit from C on top of B, it will give you the option to amend the commit via `git commit --amend`.  You can also check compilation and run your test suite at this point.  Once you are satisfied with the quality of the commit, you can type `git rebase --continue` to move on to the next commit from C.  Git will give you instructions for what to do once you enter interactive rebase mode.

After your rebase is finished, your feature branch should look like:
**your_feature** `A <- B <- C'`

I have used the label C' above to indicate that the commits from C were altered as part of your rebase.

Finally, to get this back into master you can just `git push origin your_feature:master`.  You would be fast-forwarding master with your feature branch (NOT merging).